# In clojure, how can I access and return a modified version of this collection

Tags: clojure, maps, iteration

If I have a collection like this `({:A 1 :B 2 :Goal 5} {A:2 :B 4 :Goal 2})` is there a way I can iterate through the it and use `assoc` to change all `:Goal` to some other value, say 0?
So basically given the collection above and the key `:Goal` the function returns `({:A 1 :B 2 :Goal 0} {A:2 :B 4 :Goal 0})`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(let [A '({:A 1 :B 2 :Goal 5} {:A 2 :B 4 :Goal 2})]
    (map #(assoc % :Goal 0) A))
```

or, if you are keen to use specter:

```
(let [A '({:A 1 :B 2 :Goal 5} {:A 2 :B 4 :Goal 2})]
    (setval [ALL :Goal] 0 A))
```